# How to evaluate double seasonal Holt-Winters model dshw?

Tags: time-series, prediction, accuracy

I wanna use the `dshw` method from the R `forecast` package to predict electricity consumption. I tried to use it on the `taylor` dataset available in the package. I used the parameters of the model reported in the paper (Table 2)

Taylor, J.W. (2003) Short-term electricity demand forecasting using double seasonal exponential smoothing. Journal of the Operational Research Society, 54, 799-805.

but when I evaluated the MAPE error for the next 48 half-hours I got different values than reported in the paper (the bottom curve in Figure 4).

Here is my code and comparison of MAPE errors. What am I doing wrong? How did Taylor calculated the MAPE error? Why the Figure caption says results for the 4-week post sample period when there is only 48 half-hours in the Figure? Thanks for help.

```
library("forecast")

# first 8 weeks as training set 
train <- msts(taylor[1:2688], seasonal.periods=c(48,336), ts.frequency=48)
# the rest - 4 week is test set - starts on 57th day
test <- msts(taylor[2689:4032], seasonal.periods=c(48,336), ts.frequency=48, start=57)

model <- dshw(train, alpha=0.01, beta=0.00, gamma=0.21, omega=0.24, phi=0.92)

# plot of MAPE errors for different horizonts
MAPE <- c()
for(i in 1:48) {
  MAPE <- c(MAPE, accuracy(f=model,x=test[1:i])[2,5])
}
plot(MAPE~c(1:48), ylim=c(0,3))
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible that the difference could be because the alpha, beta, gama, phi and omega values are updated at every horizon instead of being static?

Comment: Would not be in that case at least the first MAPE value the same?

Comment: From eyeballing the two charts the first value they appear to be very close. The small difference could also be because there might have been more decimal points for alpha beta gama values in the original results as opposed to two decimal points that you have it in your code